# How to recreate a svg path by removing transform attribute?

Tags: javascript, svg, path, rotation, transform

I wan to re-create a path by removing the transform attribute.
Here is my path

```
<path d="M403.50030270807304 217.03163650993932 L686.287752708073 217.03163650993932 L686.287752708073 417.3799865099393 L403.50030270807304 417.3799865099393  Z" fill="none" stroke="#006400" stroke-miterlimit="null" stroke-width="1" pointer-events="all" id="bound_0" transform="rotate(90,403.50030270807304,217.03163650993932)" stroke-dasharray="5"></path>
```

**I want to remove**  `transform="rotate(90,403.50030270807304,217.03163650993932)"`
and regenerate the path('d' attribute)

Is there any solution for it or any alternate way ?

Comment: You may wrap the transformed path in a `<g>` element and get the `getBBox()` of the g element

Comment: Is it possible to generate path again by removing this transform attribute.

Answer (score 0):

From:

```
d="M403.50030270807304 217.03163650993932 L686.287752708073 217.03163650993932 L686.287752708073 417.3799865099393 L403.50030270807304 417.3799865099393  Z"
```

Tidy up to 2 decimal places, add commas as 'x, y' separators.

```
d="M403.5, 217.03 L686.29, 217.03 L686.29, 417.38 L403.5, 417.38  Z"
```

Take away first pair of coordinates from the next coordinates and carry on until the end.

If first coord is bigger than second, result * -1.

```
d="M403.5, 217.03 L686.29, 217.03 L686.29, 417.38 L403.5, 417.38  Z"
    403.5     -    686.29    =                                282.79  
           217.03     -    217.03 =                             0
                   686.29     -    686.29 =                     0
                           217.03    -     417.38 =           200.35
                                   686.29    -     403.5 =   -282.79
                                           417.38     -   417.38 = 0
```

Put the result of each calculation one after the other into the path.
substitute L (absolute lineto) for l (relative lineto).

```
d="M403.5, 217.03 l-282.79, 0 l0, -200.35 l282.79, 0 z"
```

Shorten lineto for v and h as these are vertical and horizontal lines and take away the 0s.

```
d="M403.5, 217.03 h282.79 v200.35 h-282.79 z"
```

---

`transform="rotate(90,403.5,217.03)"` reads:

at x = 403.5, y = 217.03, rotate 90 degrees.
403.5, 217.03 is the start (origin) of the path, 
i.e. one of its corners.
            At 90degree rotation, horizontals become verticals, verticals become horizontals.Change h200.35 to h-200.35

```
d="M403.5, 217.03 h282.79 v200.35 h-282.79 z"
d="M403.5, 217.03 v282.79 h-200.35 v-282.79z"
```

Though the reality is you have a rectangle.The element rect (a self-explanatory element) should suffice and I'd urge you to use it. `<rect id="bound_0" x="203.15" y="217.03" width="200.35" height="282.79" stroke="#006400" stroke-width="1" stroke-miterlimit="null" fill="none" pointer-events="all"/>`